# How can I append records (specific rows, with multiple (but not all) columns) from one table to another

Tags: sql, ms-access

Each day ~5000 records are uploaded to tblRecordsCurrent, at some point within the next few days when those records have been processed, they need to be moved to tblRecordsHistorical.  Each record has a Foreign Key `DataSetID` that ties it to the date/time it was uploaded (Parent Table).

How, within vba, can I insert a single DataSet of tblRecordsCurrent into the tblRecordsHistorical from tblRecordsCurrent.  I cannot insert all columns as both tables contain persisted columns.

I can't put the entire `INSERT INTO tblRecordsHistorical A, B, C, D, E, F...` as it is too long for access vba.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can a list of the columns be too long? See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-specifications-HP005186808.aspx which says that it allows 64,000 characters. Is your problem the record selection rather than the column selection?

Comment: It is too long for VBA, not the statement.  The limit per line with in vba is not that high.

Comment: No it is not :) Have you used line continuation characters? There is a limit there, but it is very easy to get around `sSQL=SSQL & " More stuff"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the query in your Access database, then you can execute in in VBA the following way:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "yourQueryName", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Or

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("yourQueryName")
```

Or

```
CurrentDb.Execute "qryAddLoginfoRow"
```

This allows you to execute the query without having the query stored in your VBA code.  But you are also able to execute this via a query in [`VBA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834799.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO tblRecordsHistorical (col1, col2...) 
SELECT col1, col2...
FROM tblRecordsCurrent
```

EDIT:

You can create a long SQL string by concatenating the string together:

```
SQLString = "INSERT INTO tblRecordsHistorical (col1, col2...) " & _
            " SELECT ... " & _
            " FROM tblRecordsCurrent "
```

Comment: I understand how to execute an action query within VBA, but I need to be able to specify criteria on the fly.  I've created the SQL statement using the query builder, then tried to copy it to a docmd.runsql and it's too long.

Comment: Avoid DoCmd.RunSQL, it leads you into wrong doing, .Execute against a connection, but that is an aside.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the string together?  SQLString = SQLString & " more SQL" [Example of strings in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802120/building-sql-strings-in-access-vba)

Comment: @Remou I was just showing it as an example. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Building up the SQL Statement over a few lines worked a treat, if one of you can post that as a possible answer I will accept it and UPVOTE both of your comments...

Comment: Remou, what did you mean about docmd.runsql having issues, never used any other ways to execute a statement.

Comment: @aSystemOverload With DoCmd.RunSQL you get system warnings, which you will be tempted to switch off with set warnings and this is not a good idea : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Comment: @aSystemOverload please see my edit with an example of a string concatenation