# How to run query based on information from InputBox?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

On my form I have a button which the user can click. It will then prompt the user with 3 input boxes, where the user can enter in the information that he wants to run a query on. I want the query to run based on the values that he enters into the 3 inputboxes, but I cannot seem to figure this out. The query is based on another table in my database. Here is the code I've written. It won't compile because I have too many arguments. This is probably because I don't know how to pass variables with the DoCmd.OpenQuery command.

```
    Private Sub VariableQuery_Click()

    Dim strProdCode As String
    Dim strCampCode As String
    Dim strMailDate As String

    strProdCode = InputBox("Enter Product Code", "Product Code")
    strCampCode = InputBox("Enter Campaign Code", "Campaign Code")
    strMailDate = InputBox("Enter Mail Date", "Mail Date")

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "contribution", , , "[PRODUCT_CODE]=" & strProdCode & _
    "[CAMPAIGN_CODE]=" & strCampCode & "[MAIL_DATE]=" & strMailDate

    End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. The name of the query I am trying to run is "contribution". PRODUCT_CODE, CAMPAIGN_CODE, and MAIL_DATE are the names of the fields in the database and PRODUCT_CODE and CAMPAIGN_CODE are both text fields, and MAIL_DATE is a Date/Time field.

Comment: Is the query a `SELECT` query or some kind of action query?

Comment: It's a make table query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a different way to do this but how I would approach the problem is by creating the SQL string

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT ... INTO ... " _
       & "FROM ... " _
       & "WHERE [PRODUCT_CODE]='" & strProdCode &"' AND [CAMPAIGN_CODE]='" & strCampCode & "' AND [MAIL_DATE]=#" & strMailDate & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Things to note

- When you have `WHERE` kind of clauses you have to qualify the values of the fields appropriately e.g. `''` around strings, `##` around dates and nothing around numbers
- DoCmd.RunSQL I believe only runs actions queries e.g. `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc.  Plain `SELECT` are not action queries.
- If you want to hide the warnings that popup there are two ways to do it, one is to use `CurrentDB.Execute(strSQL)` instead or to use `DoCmd.SetWarnings(False)` and `DoCmd.SetWarnings(True)`

Edit (Possible helpful links)

- http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html
- [Building SQL strings in Access/VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802120/building-sql-strings-in-access-vba)
- You can Google "building sql strings in ms access" or some variation of that for more sources

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL. What do these two lines mean? And where do I specify which query I want to run.                   s= "SELECT ... INTO ... " _
& "FROM ... " _

Comment: I made a typo, `s = ` should be `strSQL = `.  Now what this looks like is something like `SELECT MyFieldsName INTO MyTableName ...`.  If you're completely unfamiliar with SQL I'm not sure if I have a non-SQL method to do what you want to do.  I've edited some links that might be a good starting point to learn some of the basics if you want to learn how to use SQL.

Comment: OK thank you very much. I'm going to spend this afternoon learning SQL and then use your code and hopefully I'll be able to figure it out. Thanks again!