# Data type mismatch in criteria expression when adding command

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I solve a Data type mismatch in criteria expression when adding a command to my Crystal Report? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and SAP Crystal Report.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael De Villa, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend you [edit] your question to improve it; images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. If you would like to include details of your code or error messages, please copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the question directly.

Comment: try providing start time and end time parameters without quotes.. also what is the datatype of dates in database and also your parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data type mismatch in criteria expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775066/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression)